# Are any software updates scheduled for Juno?

Tags: juno, flyby, software

Juno is approaching her gravity assist. During the course of the maneuver, several on-board systems will be powered up - in all probability they are nominal, having already been checked after launch.

Assuming, say, a new algorithm has been developed, or an instrument is made more efficient by a code update, could Juno's mission control opt to schedule such an update during the course of the maneuver?

- Are there any software updates scheduled for Juno during the maneuver (either before or after perigee)?
- What is the process of performing an instruction update on spacecraft instruments?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

During the maneuver?  Certainly not.  You don't mess with the spacecraft configuration around or anywhere near critical events unless it is absolutely necessary.

Modern spacecraft are all designed to permit their flight software to be updated.  A complete image of the new flight software is uploaded the spacecraft.  The image's integrity is verified, and then it is set to be the load used on just the next reboot.  The previous image is kept in place in case you need to fall back on it.  A subsequent reboot will go back to the old one as a safety net.  You boot on the new image, check it out, and if all is well, you make the new image the default for future reboots.

Comment: I'm sure if they are going to do it, it'll be sometime in the next month or so, close enough to be useful, and not during a critical time.